# CanCan AccessDenied exception assigns the controller variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception, rspec, cancan

I'm using CanCan in my application. I'm testing my controller to see if it behaves as expected. 
In my controller there is a manual checking of the permissions:

```
authorize!(:read, @booking)
```

It raises an CanCan::AccessDenied exception and it redirects to root_url as it is defined in my ApplicationController.

My concern is that I was testing that it should not assign booking as a variable:

```
expect(assigns[:booking]).to_not eq(booking)
```

However, it does assign booking! 
I was wondering if this issue is known as it an unauthorised user shouldn't receive any internal information about what he was asking for (even though it is being redirect he could see it in the response)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use `load_and_authorize_resource`, it will assign the variables in a before_filter. [Read here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#user-content-2-check-abilities--authorization) -> "It will use a before filter to load the resource into an instance variable and authorize it for every action." This also applies if you use `load_resource`.

Comment: But it is still assigning it. It does not solve the problem. It is still in the response.

Comment: Are you using `load_and_authorize_resource` or `load_resource` for that controller? If you do not want it assigned, do not use these two for that controller, or you could add an except block: i.e. `load_and_authorize_resource except: 'my_action'`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. CanCan and CanCanCan are completely safe. Assigns is something that Rspec manages (more info would be welcome). There is no info about @booking in the response.